# OpenDNS setup help

Tags: dns, troubleshooting, networksetup

Tried to setup Opendns, but this time it did not work (in my previous install, it worked just fine, unfortunately my pc crashed and had to re-install my OS), followed the [setup guide](https://www.opendns.com/setupguide/), unfortunately did not work. Can someone please point me to how to fix/troubleshoot where the problem is?
OS: MX Linux (based on Debian 11)
when I went to [OpenDNS test page](https://welcome.opendns.com/), it said "You aren't using OpenDNS yet.". I went to check my IPv4 setting, OpenDNS servers are listed there, and I did add

```
supersede domain-name-servers 208.67.222.222,208.67.220.220;
```

into my /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf (before the 'require subnet-mask'), not sure if there's anything else I need to do.

Comment: We will need a lot more info than that, what distro? what does not work (resolution? not registering the fact you changed the server?

Comment: @NicolasFormichella updated my OP to add additional detail.

Comment: I removed your tagging of the title with "[SOLVED]". Accepting an answer (ever your own) marks a question as resolved. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer and https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the right solution, but solved my problem. According to this [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N1bLAm36BLs), you need to change IPv4 Settings to Automatic (DHCP) addresses only, once saved, OpenDNS started working. Don't know what's the difference between Automatic (DHCP) addresses only vs Automatic (DHCP).

Comment: It is best to not tack an additional answer on to the end of a question, else it starts to look like a thread in a forum. Either ask a new question, or simply state that you don't know what the difference is.

Comment: @Greenonline thanks for this tip